# TypeError: undefined is not a function Input Validation AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I'm doing some input validation using angular, but when the function is called each of the elements come back as undefined. I've included the important code below, please let me know if this is not enough. I appreciate any help that I can get.

JS

```
angular.module('app.directives', [])
.directive('mrnCheck', [function () {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        //console.log(firstMRN.val());
        var firstMRN = '#' + attrs.mrnCheck;
        elem.add('test');
        //console.log(firstMRN.val());
        //console.log(firstMRN);
        elem.add(firstMRN).on('keyup', function () {
            scope.$apply(function () {
                ctrl.$setValidity('mrnmatch', elem.val() === $(firstMRN).val());
            });
        });
    }
}
```

}]);

HTML

```
<div class = "row" ng-show="<?php echo $_SESSION["associate"]; ?>">
    </br>
    <form name = "UploadForm" class="input-group" role="form">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">MRN</span>
            <input type="MRN" ng-model="MRN1" class="form-control" id="MRN1" placeholder="Patient MRN" ng-required="" />
        </div>
        </br>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">MRN</span>
            <input type="MRN" ng-model="MRN2" class="form-control" id="MRN2" placeholder="Confirm MRN" ng-required="" mrn-Check="MRN1" />
            <span ng-show="UploadForm.MRN2.$error.MRNmatch">MRN values must match!</span>
        </div>
    </form>
 </div>
```

Error

at link (httpsomeLink/imageinbox/IIExpress/app/app.js:237:9)
    at nodeLinkFn (httpsomeLink/imageinbox/IIExpress/app/assets/angular/angular.js:6704:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (httpsomeLink/imageinbox/IIExpress/app/assets/angular/angular.js:6098:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (httpsomeLink/imageinbox/IIExpress/app/assets/angular/angular.js:6101:13)
    at nodeLinkFn (httpsomeLink/imageinbox/IIExpress/app/assets/angular/angular.js:6698:24)
    at compositeLinkFn (httpsomeLink/imageinbox/IIExpress/app/assets/angular/angular.js:6098:13)
    at nodeLinkFn (httpsomeLink/imageinbox/IIExpress/app/assets/angular/angular.js:6698:24)
    at compositeLinkFn (httpsomeLink/imageinbox/IIExpress/app/assets/angular/angular.js:6098:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (httpsomeLink/imageinbox/IIExpress/app/assets/angular/angular.js:6101:13)
    at nodeLinkFn (httpsomeLink/imageinbox/IIExpress/app/assets/angular/angular.js:6698:24)

Please note, line 237 is the line that begins with elem.add. Also, somelink represents a real link, as I could not post the real one.

Comment: can you setup a fiddler ? Also specify the full error from console

Comment: Sure, I've heard of it, but am not very familiar. What data would be useful to you out of it?

Comment: copy full at from console. e.g before at link there should be some error

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work properly, at least I don't think so, just a bunch of ClientHello record was too long entries. I think what I've pasted below may be what you're looking for?

Comment: angular.js:10061 TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at link (http://192.168.1.252/imageinbox/IIExpress/app/assets/angular/angular.js:6101:13)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://192.168.1.252/imageinbox/IIExpress/app/assets/angular/angular.js:6698:24) <input type="MRN" ng-model="MRN2" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" id="MRN2" placeholder="Confirm MRN" ng-required="" mrn-check="MRN1">
http://192.168.1.252/imageinbox/IIExpress/app/?user=associate Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

Comment: I had to delete a lot, since it was too long for the comment box.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. The `input type="MRN" => type="text"`

```
<form name="UploadForm" class="input-group" role="form">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">MRN</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="MRN1" class="form-control" id="MRN1" placeholder="Patient MRN" ng-required="" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">MRN</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="MRN2" class="form-control" id="MRN2" placeholder="Confirm MRN" ng-required="" mrn-check="MRN1" />
        <span ng-show="UploadForm.MRN2.$error.MRNmatch">MRN values must match!</span>
    </div>
</form>

angular.module('app.directives', [])
.directive('mrnCheck', [function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            //console.log(firstMRN.val());
            var firstMRN = '#' + attrs.mrnCheck;
            elem.add('test');
            //console.log(firstMRN.val());
            //console.log(firstMRN);
            elem.add(firstMRN).on('keyup', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('mrnmatch', elem.val() === jQuery(firstMRN).val());
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: I just tried that, and it's throwing TypeError: undefined is not a function at the first instance of elem.add

Comment: Hmm, maybe I have it placed incorrectly in my .js file? I can upload the rest of it if you think the error resides somewhere else? (I assume it must, since it's working on your system).

Comment: What tab do you want the data out of? I'm sorry that this is such a basic question, but I'm not used to using fiddler.